# Searching with Jquery - Work for multiple terms

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I found this great snippet online for a searchable FAQ. However, I was wondering if anyone knew how it could be modified to work with multiple terms.

http://jsfiddle.net/pT6dB/

On the example above, I would like to be enter "paper Earth" to have both example results returned. If I enter that now, it doesn't return anything. I guess I want to make it equivalent to searching "paper" OR "Earth".

Any help would be much appreciated.

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is matching the search string against a regular expression to get all words. Then, for each `li` you check whether its text contains any of the words and show or hide appropriately. I've used `array.some` which is only available on newer browsers, though.

I've tidied it up a bit as well - not all code was necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/pT6dB/29/.

```
// no need for preventDefault here - clicking a <strong> doesn't do anything
$('li strong').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find('em').slideToggle();
});

// the "input" event is available on newer browsers, and is also fired when e.g.
// pasting or dragging text
$('#search').on("input", function(e) {
    // make it case-insensitive, and match against a regexp that matches
    // non-space characters
    var words = $(this).val().toLowerCase().match(/\S+/g);
    if (!words) {  // no match, i.e. no words found
        $('#result li').show();
    } else {
        $('#result li').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var show = words.some(function(word) {
                return ~text.indexOf(word);  // ~ with indexOf means "contains"
            });
            $(this).toggle(show);  // will show or hide depending on "show"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very detailed answer. I am a bit concerned about the array.some compatibility though, does this have to be used?

Comment: @James Willson: No, not at all. It's a convenience function that returns `true` as soon as the function inside returns `true`. You could easily replace that with a `for` loop.

Comment: Could you show me how? I don't have a clue about this stuff, then I would award you the question since you have been very diligent to remove the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the value by the " " character using the javascript string.split function.  Then loop through each element to see if there is a match.

For example:

```
 $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
        var s = $(this).val().trim();
        if (s === '') {
            $('#result LI').show();
            return true;
        }

        $('#result LI').hide();

        splits = s.split(" ");

        for(x in splits){
            $('#result LI:contains(' + splits[x]+ ')').show();
        }

        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry I could only pick one